# Bootstrap 4.0 tabs don't switch the tab panes

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, tabs

I have another one question on the improperly working tabs in Bootstrap 4.
I've tried a lot of examples from official documentation, from Stackoverflow and others. The issue is still the same.

So, I need to make switching tabs with contents. I took a code from Bootstrap 4 docs (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/components/navs/#javascript-behavior), put it to my page and linked all css and js.

The issue is that **the tabs are switching** properly, but **the tab panes didn't change**. There is no JS errors, proper js include order, all recommended version of js scripts. I have no ideas, what to do.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="/site/signup/advertiser#home" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="/site/signup/advertiser#profile" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="/site/signup/advertiser#contact" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">1</div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">2</div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">3</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Please, explain me, what is wrong here.

Many thanks in advance!

Comment: The issue was that my SilverStripe CMS has rewrited the anchors by default by adding a path before it. Disabling this option fixed the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Bootstrap Case</title>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="container">
            <ul class="nav nav-tabs" id="myTab" role="tablist">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link active" id="home-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#home1" role="tab" aria-controls="home" aria-selected="true">Home</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="profile-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#profile1" role="tab" aria-controls="profile" aria-selected="false">Profile</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link" id="contact-tab" data-toggle="tab" href="#contact1" role="tab" aria-controls="contact" aria-selected="false">Contact</a>
                </li>
            </ul>
            <div class="tab-content" id="myTabContent">
                <div class="tab-pane fade show active" id="home1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="home-tab">1</div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="profile1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="profile-tab">2</div>
                <div class="tab-pane fade" id="contact1" role="tabpanel" aria-labelledby="contact-tab">3</div>
            </div>
        </div>

        <script type="application/javascript" src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script type="application/javascript" src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Your href should refer to your tab id only can work.

Comment: Thank you! I've just realized this too, BUT how can I do that? In the source html all hrefs are without the path - exactly as you wrote. But in the browser I see the path added before every anchor.

Comment: The issue was that my SilverStripe CMS has rewrited the anchors by default by adding a path before it. Disabling this option fixed the problem.